# Will a charger for Canon 60D batteries work on 40D batteries?

Tags: canon, battery, canon-60d, charger, canon-40d

I know that the batteries for 60D and 40D are not the same, but is the charger compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sadly it isn't.

I had a 40D and sold it when I upgraded it to the 60D. Strange how it still doesn't feel like an upgrade lol :)

Comment: well you can record video now :)

Comment: And that in a nutshell is the reason I upgraded my lovely old 40D :) Do miss the build quality of that though. Even the 6D I use as main camera doesn't come close to the build quality of the 40D.

Comment: The true upgrade for the 40D/50D was the 7D. The 60D was a mixed bag. The 70D recovered most of what was lost in the xxD line.

Comment: 7D was definitely next in line to the 50D. The 70D looks an interesting camera especially for video.